# Injecting content script programmatically to chrome extension multiple times throws syntax error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope

I am new to extension development. I am trying to inject a content script programmatically as described in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#programmatic).

This is my `background.js`.

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  try {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      files: ["content-script.js"],
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

And this is my `conten-script.js`.

```js
const message = "Hello Stranger";
window.alert(message);
```

Clicking the extension icon more than once throws the error below.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'message' has already been declared (at content-script.js:1:1)
```

But when I run the same code in a function, it works just fine.

```js
(function () {
  const message = "Hello Stranger";
  window.alert(message);
})();
```

It looks like chrome has some kind of "global environment" where the script runs and that environment maintains references to the variables declared in the previous execution. I would love to know what is happening here. The documentation doesn't have an explanation( I am yet to come across if it does).

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` in your `conten-script.js` - this is supposed to dump the environment.

Comment: The content scripts run in the same environment of the web page, it's conceptually the same as running a new `script` in the web page, the only difference being that variables and code of content scripts are isolated from the page.

Comment: Global variables vs the same hidden by IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) and error sounds self explanatory ??

Comment: @Jared `this` inside `content-script.js` is the same one for the webpage. `console.log(this.message)` is `undefined`. Like @wOxxOm mentioned, `content-script.js` is isolated from the web page.